# Ansible block in role not acting as expected

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have ansible 2.2.1.0 and I have this role:

```
- block:
    - shell: echo 1
    - shell: fail
    - shell: echo 2
  rescue:
    - shell: echo 3
  always:
    - shell: echo 4

- name: running something after the block
  shell: echo 5
```

If I run this role, the first part of the block fails because of the "fail" command (which does not exist :) "stderr: /bin/sh: 1: fail: not found") so the rescue kicks + always. But the last task, the one "running something after the block" never runs. The play finises!

Why is that ? 
The expected result I would see it as: if the first part of the block fails rescue kicks in + always (if any) and then continues the play run with the rest of the tasks.

In the documentation there is nothing about this.

Is there a workaround this ?

Comment: When adding tags, please read their descriptions and do not use the ones that contain "do not use" guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20736) in 2.2.1. Downgrade to 2.2.0 if this is required workflow for you.